# Bluetooth restart programmatically in android 7 nougat

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-7.0-nougat

I have an application which runs in the background and restarts bluetooth programmatically using
...

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

...

It works fine in Android Marshmallow but not in Nougat. If anyone has come across a solution to this please let me know.

Comment: how exactly it doesn't work? Does it crash, or just has no effect?

Comment: It does not crash, it just have no effect. My  targetSdkVersion 23 and i run the application on nougat.

Comment: Did you found any solution I have the same case please answer if you have got any rep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211938/voice-cannot-be-heard-from-bluetooth-headset-in-nougat-devices-android

Answer (score 1):

Using Handler you will easily restart bluetooth.

```
        tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialogConConnect.dismiss();
            }
        });
        tvOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String sec = edtConC.getText().toString();
                int second = Integer.parseInt(sec);
                int minus = second - 1;
                int mSecond = minus*1000;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                        }
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                           public void run() {
                                if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                                    bluetoothAdapter.enable();
                                }
                            }
                        },1000);
                    }
                },mSecond);
                dialogConConnect.dismiss();

            }
        });
        dialogConConnect.show();
    }
});
```